# Same-origin policy being violated when using react-stripe-checkout

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using React 0.15 and [react-stripe-checkout](https://github.com/azmenak/react-stripe-checkout). When the `ReactStripeCheckout` component is used, I will get the following error in the console:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

The problem will go away when I remove the `ReactStripeCheckout` component.

I'm not sure why this would be happening though, and before posting this as an issue on Github, I wanted to see if anyone else has had a similar problem, or can spot the problem right away.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you don't use `react-stripe-checkout`, but instead just include a Checkout button on your page?

Comment: Actually, I did not, but discovered the source of the problem already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this problem occurs because of a Chrome extension, Recent Tabs, that I had running.

I should have done this immediately, but upon inspecting the stack trace, I found that injected code was causing the problem from the extension. Once I disabled the extension this problem goes away.

I'm choosing to put this in an answer, because I can see other people running into the same problem where a same-origin policy problem occurs unexpectedly -- check your browser extensions first as a possible source of the problem.